# DuckDB: turn dataframe dictionary column into MAP column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duckdb

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column containing dictionary values. I'd like to query this dataframe using DuckDB and convert the result to another dataframe, and have the type preserved across the query.

DuckDB has the [`MAP`](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/data_types/map) data type which looks like a good match for a dictionary, but when selecting the column it's turned into a `VARCHAR`, and results in a string-type column if I convert back to a dataframe.

Is there some way to preserve the type, or at least a good way to convert the string back to a dictionary when generating the new dataframe?

```py
>>> # Create a dataframe with a column containing a dictionary
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[{'some': 'dict', 'with': 'stuff'}]], columns=['mycol'])
>>> df
                               mycol
0  {'some': 'dict', 'with': 'stuff'}
>>> type(df['mycol'][0])
<class 'dict'>

>>> # Select that column using DuckDB - it becomes a VARCHAR
>>> duckdb.query('select mycol from df')
---------------------
-- Expression Tree --
---------------------
Subquery

---------------------
-- Result Columns  --
---------------------
- mycol (VARCHAR)

---------------------
-- Result Preview  --
---------------------
mycol
VARCHAR
[ Rows: 1]
{'some': 'dict', 'with': 'stuff'}


>>> # Converting the query result to another dataframe results in a string-type column
>>> df2 = duckdb.query('select mycol from df').to_df()
>>> df2
                               mycol
0  {'some': 'dict', 'with': 'stuff'}
>>> type(df2['mycol'][0])
<class 'str'>

>>> # An explicit cast to MAP doesn't work
>>> duckdb.query('select CAST(mycol as MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR)) from df')
---------------------
-- Expression Tree --
---------------------
Subquery

---------------------
-- Result Columns  --
---------------------
- CAST(mycol AS MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>) (MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>)

---------------------
-- Result Preview  --
---------------------
Conversion Error: Conversion Error: Unimplemented type for cast (VARCHAR -> MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a known issue in DuckDB (https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/2450).

You can workaround this issue by using PyArrow.

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

df = pd.DataFrame([[{'some': 'dict', 'with': 'stuff'}]], columns=['mycol'])
con = duckdb.connect()
arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

con.execute("select * from arrow_table").fetchall()
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, infact I was trying to learn duckdb and after stuggling with the documentation of I just completely switched to pyarrow.